# Ruby on rails - Apache config file error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, apache

I am reading a book about "Ruby on Rails" and now I have to deploy my application using Apache and Passenger. Everything seems to be installed properly but when I have finally add the following code in the Apache config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName depot.yourhost.com
   DocumentRoot /home/gotqn/Aptana Projects/depot/public/

   <Directory /home/gotqn/Aptana Projects/depot/public>
      AllowOverride all
      Options -MultiViews
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and try to restart the Apache:

> $ sudo apachectl restart

I get the following error:

> Syntax error on line 245 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
>
> DocumentRoot takes one argument, Root directory of the document tree
>
> Action 'restart' failed.
>
> The Apache error log may have more information.

The line 245 refers to the following line:

```
DocumentRoot /home/gotqn/Aptana Projects/depot/public/
```

Any ideas what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spaces are not allowed in this line, just put the whole path in double quotes

```
DocumentRoot "/home/gotqn/Aptana Projects/depot/public/"
```

Answer (score 2):

You used spaces in directory path you need to escape the spaces or create path without spaces.
Instead of adding it to apache2.conf create one file(called newsite or something) in **/etc/apache2/site-available** and write the same thing  in that file. And then run following commad:

```
    sudo a2ensite newsite
```

Then restart server and add your server name to /etc/hosts